# Rewrite part of url .htacces

Tags: mod-rewrite

I need to redirect an url from

http://mydomain.com/download/**filename.zip**

to

https://dl.dropbox.com/u/0000/**filename.zip**

How can I do this using mod_rewrite?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make a `.htaccess` file in root of your first domain, with this rule:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule download/(.+) https://dl.dropbox.com/u/0000/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    # Check to see if mod_rewrite is installed / avaliable
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on

# Check to see if file or directory exists
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# Rewrite to Dropbox URL. Make sure you change the data after "/u/" (9502594) to your own user ID
RewriteRule ^e/(.*)$ http://dl.dropbox.com/u/9502594/$1 [L,QSA]    # Embedded File
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://dl.dropbox.com/u/9502594/$1?dl=1 [L,QSA] # Force Download (Default)
</IfModule>
```